# POST http://localhost:3000/add 404 (Not Found) Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-router, mern

I am doing the project using MERN stack. So I have compiled the code successfully by running npm start on both client side and server side. It will open http://localhost:3000/ when I fill the data and click on submit. It is not sending the data to mongodb.

Want to know whether this problem occurs on client side or server side.

[image: Here is the console output]

As in given picture it is showing error in stepContext.js
Here is code of stepContext.js which comes under client side

**stepContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'

export const multiStepContext = createContext();

export default function StepContext(props) {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [currentStep , setCurrentStep] = useState(1);
    const [userData , setUserData] = useState([]);
    const [finalData , setFinalData] = useState([]);
const [transferData , setTransferData] = useState([]);

  async  function submitData(){
        setFinalData(finalData => [...finalData,userData]);
        console.log(userData)
     await   axios.post("/add",userData);
        setUserData('');
        setCurrentStep(1);
        history.push("/customers");
    }
  async  function sendMoney() {
     await   axios.post("/customer/money" , transferData);
        history.push("/customers");
    }

    return (
       <multiStepContext.Provider value={{currentStep, setCurrentStep,userData , setUserData,finalData , setFinalData, submitData,transferData,setTransferData,sendMoney}}>
           {props.children}
       </multiStepContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

***Backend code***

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const PORT  = 5000;
const DB = 'mongodb+srv://salunkherushikesh859:<passwd>@cluster0.tpdffqx.mongodb.net/login?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(DB,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useFindAndModify:false,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
}).then(() => console.log("DB connected"))
.catch((e) => console.log(e))

 
app.use(express.json());
const userRoute = require("./routes/userData")
app.use(userRoute)
 
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    const path = require("path");
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}
app.listen(PORT,() => console.log(`PORT is running at ${PORT}`))
```

I have defined routes  in **userdata.js** file
Here is code

```
const express = require("express");
const transactions = require("../models/transactionSchema");
const router = express.Router();
const user = require("../models/userSchema");

router.post("/add", async (req, res) => {
  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    
  } = req.body;
  if (
    !firstName ||
    !lastName ||
     
  ) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please fill all the details" });
  }
  const newUser = new user({
    firstName,
    lastName,
   
  });

  await newUser.save();
});

router.get("/customers", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const User = await user.find();
    res.send(User);
     console.log(User)
    //   res.status(200).json(User.favourite);
    // console.log(User.favourite)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json();
  }
});

router.get("/customers/:id", async (req, res) => {
  // const { id} = req.body;
  // console.log(req.params.id);
  const data = await user.findById(req.params.id);
  // console.log(data);
  if (data) {
    res.send(data);
     console.log(data);
  }
});

router.put("/customer/money", async (req, res) => {
  // console.log(req.body)
  try {
    const { id, count, id2 } = req.body;
    const data = await user.findById(id);
    const data2 = await user.findById(id2);
    data2.amount = count + data2.amount;
    data.amount = data.amount - count;
    data.save();
    data2.save();
    res.send("updated successfull");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
  // data.update({amount:amount1})

  // res.send("The amount is debited rupees from _ and creidet to rupess _ ")
});


router.post("/transactions" , async(req,res) => {
  try {
  const { id, count, id2 } = req.body;
  const data = await user.findById(id);
  const data2 = await user.findById(id2);
// console.log(req.body);
  const newTrans = new transactions({
    userOne : data.name,
    userTwo:data2.name,
    amount:count
  })

  await newTrans.save();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
})


router.get("/gettransactions", async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const data = await transactions.find();
    res.send(data);
    // console.log(data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).json();
  }
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You don't appear to have any of the relevant routes coded in your express app.

Comment: I have added the code for routes in userdata.js file

Comment: first thing you have not added the password in your Mongodb URL

Comment: There is a syntax error inside `/add`. `if (!firstName || !lastName ||)` that final `||` cannot be there. Is this a typo in the example? Or is this also present in your actual code?

Comment: It is already present in actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring many articles finally I got a solution .
By referring @sachin answer I got
`'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

Then I followed certain steps:-

Stop the ***Node.js*** server.

Run below command

```
npm install cors --save
```

Add following lines to your server.js or index.js

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors()) // Use this after the variable declaration
```

then after restarting the server and client side it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend code is running on port 5000.
You have mentioned the API as `/add` in your react code which will hit to port 3000.
Instead, try replacing `/add` with `http://localhost:5000/add`

Comment: in which code? in **userdata.js** ?

Comment: I have added what you tell in the react code Now it is showing this error message including previous one `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/add' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: This answered your question, so it makes sense to click the empty check mark next to it to mark it as correct. Don't ask two questions in one, and please google for errors first, your error message you posted is a question asked dozens of times a day on Stackoverflow, and there are thousands of answers to it.

Comment: then post the link here . I don't find any source link